# Родительский, дочерний блок

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Ситуация следующая:

```
<div class="block">
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="child"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Есть элемент "block", у которого ширина 100% от окна браузера, а есть элемент "parent", который имеет фиксированную ширину например 1390px. Внутри "parent" должен храниться элемент "child" у которого ширина 15% и она также масштабируется  от окна браузера как у "block", а не от "parent". Так вот, как нужно реализовывать сию проблему?

Comment: в чем заключается проблема?

Comment: Чтобы каким-нибудь образом элемент "child" был внутри элемента "parent", но ширина его масштабировалась как у элемента "block"

Comment: Как у элемента `block`? или в зависимости от ширины экрана?

Comment: Ну это я образно говорю, чтоб "child" ширина масштабировалась как "block", который масштабируется от ширины экрана. Да главное, чтоб "child" ширина масштабировался от ширины экрана, а не от своего родителя "parent", у которого ширина 1390px

Comment: Как вариант ```.child``` - ```width: 15vw;```

Comment: Нет, это тоже не подходит, в общем я неправильно объяснил. Практикую вот этот макет: https://www.figma.com/file/gBEwh0z9OcWrV6TGs8H2Ij/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE-%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0?node-id=27%3A2
Там внизу есть заголовок "My portfolio", а рядом с ним линия. Сам заголовок и линию хочу поместить внутрь блока с картинками, но хочу, чтобы линия масштабировалась  в ширину в зависимости от размера body блока наверное правильно будет сказать

Comment: А сам блок с картинками имеет фиксированную ширину 1390px

Comment: Я не знаю правильно ли я делаю вёрстку этой части, может надо вообще только заголовок оставить в блоке с картинками, а линию вывести в body и потом с помощью absolute разместить рядом с заголовком, но мне кажется так неправильно делать

Comment: @Ronald Reagan https://jsfiddle.net/f6jkxw4q/

Comment: @soledar10 не открывает ссылку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.portfolio {
  background-color: #000;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.portfolio__container {
  max-width: 1390px;
  max-width: 390px; /* for test */
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3rem 1rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid #00f;
}

.portfolio__title {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}

.portfolio__title::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(100% + 10px);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: -.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio">
  <div class="portfolio__container">
    <h2 class="portfolio__title">Portflio</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Если я правильно понял, суть в том, что перемещаем в правый край линию и задаём макс.ширину экрана и тогда у нас линия всегда будет уходить за страницу вне зависимости от ширины страницы

Comment: @Ronald Reagan да

Comment: Спасибо большое Вам ещё раз.